# Replace character after specific character in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a string like this :

```
Hello-world-Hi-people-Hello-everybody
```

And i want to str-replace '-' by spaces and have this result :

```
Hello-world Hi-people Hello-everybody
```

I have tried :

```
 str_replace('-', ' ', $mystring);
```

But this is not what i'm looking for

Comment: Learn a bit of http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Also, I suspect the actual question is how to replace `-` ***before a capital letter***...!?

Comment: No in fact the string letters are capitals : HELLO-WORLD-HI-PEOPLE-HELLO-EVERYBODY

Comment: Oh, okay, so you have neither expressed what you want precisely in English nor did you give an actual accurate sample of your data... Sure, we'll get our crystal balls then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of trying to select "-", focus on which strings you want to isolate? For instance, is it "Hello" or "Hi" followed by one word? Then this could work:

```
<?php
$input = "Hello-world-Hi-people-Hello-everybody";
preg_match_all("/(Hello|Hi)-\w*/", $input, $output);
echo implode(" ", $output[0]);
```

I'm not very efficient with regex myself, but this could show the way.